# How do I allow users to download my code for them to review?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, source-code

How can I allow someone on Stack Overflow to download my source code so they can review it?

Comment: Tell them that they're allowed to? What am I missing? Or don't you know where to upload them in the first place?

Comment: That sounds wrong for two reasons. 1) Your posts should be self-contained. That is, all the code needed should be included and there should not be an insane amount of it. 2) code reviews are not on-topic for SO. So what is it exactly you want to ask?

Comment: I had an Xcode issue and someone on stack overflow said that I should upload my files so they can run them to help me with the issue. However, to keep from adding 1 question onto another I posted the question here.

Comment: Just upload them to a free file hosting service, and link to it in a comment below your question.  If it's small enough (5MB or so), you can email a zip file to them.

Comment: Nobody's bashing you, it's just hard to guess what the actual problem is without context

Comment: Did not mean bashing, so I took it off the comment. Just seems half of the comments I get are about how/what I am saying instead of looking at the actual problem. I know I am a newbie and it shows. But I am trying, that is why I posted the question here.

Comment: @DavidHall sometimes we need to ask questions to clarify how/what you are saying so that we can better understand the actual problem. As Bart says, we're here to help, but sometimes that involves seeking further clarification.

Comment: Once again, it's fine for you to ask this. And I for one am glad you did. It helps you prevent mistakes which might cause downvotes or closure of your SO question. So well done. All we're trying to do is help you prevent typical mistakes. So don't worry, I don't know how you're interpreting the comments, but we're only trying to be supportive. (Btw, removed my "take it to chat" comment, since that's not yet an option for you. You need more rep for that).

Comment: Part of debugging involves you reducing your code to the smallest sample that still reproduces the problem. You're expected to do this before coming to Stack Overflow for help. If you can't do this then your problem isn't right for Stack Overflow and you should look elsewhere for help. A question that involves large portions of your program is the reason we have the "too localized" vote-to-close reason. Fixing *your* code isn't going to help anybody at any point in the future, save you.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are numerous outside services that provide this capability.

That said, most of SO's community members prefer a [short, self-contained, correct (compilable) example](http://sscce.org/), or at least something that is short enough to fit within the limits of a regular post.  Stack Overflow isn't really suitable for large-scale code review requests.